# One Loop with Repeated Result

Tags: laravel-5

I want to view images from database by looping in my blade. Why is that the result of this loop has repeated twice?

```
 @for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
    @foreach($tran['listImage'] as $image)
      data-image-{!! $i !!}="../Transaction/{!! $image->tran_file !!}"
    @endforeach 
  @endfor
```

//the result

> data-image-0="../Transaction/5kKhFq_avatar2.png"
>
> data-image-0="../Transaction/KLGNTm_download.jpg"
>
> data-image-1="../Transaction/5kKhFq_avatar2.png"
>
> data-image-1="../Transaction/KLGNTm_download.jpg"

Comment: You should remove the outer for loop

Comment: Sir the outer loop is intended for counter indicator so that i can use it to pass the count in my javascript

Answer (score 0):

As @mrida answered you should remove the outer for loop. That is what is causing the loop run twice.

If you need a count you can just get the count of the array so you can use it on your javascript.

```
@foreach($tran['listImage'] as $image)
      data-image-{!! $i !!}="../Transaction/{!! $image->tran_file !!}"
@endforeach 

$total_count = count($tran);
...
...
...
<script>
    alert('{{ $total_count}}');
</script>
```